# Can a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ have a derivative at $a$ with rank $<2$ and still have a tangent plane at $a$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, jacobian

If $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is differentiable at $a$ such that the rank of $Df(a)$ is $2$, then the trace of $Df(a)$ is a plane tangent to the function $f$ at $a$.

The only examples I've been able to come up of a case where $Df(a)<2$ consist in the function $f$ tracing a curve, for example $$f:(x,y)\mapsto (x,2x,3x).$$

---

Is it possible to have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $Df$ exists at $a$ with rank less than $2$ and there is a plane tangent to $f$ at $a$?

Put another way, does the fact that the rank of $Df(a)$ is less than $2$ necessarily imply that there is no tangent plant of $f$ at $a$?

Comment: What do you mean by a tangent plane of a function? Do you consider the image of the function and ask for a tangent plane at $f(a)$?

Comment: The smooth bijection $f:\mathbf{R}\to\mathbf{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x^3$ is worth contemplating.

Comment: @PaulFrost yes.

Comment: What is your notion of a tangent plane to a subset which is not a smooth submanifold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x,y) = (x^3,y^3,0)$. The image of $f$ is $\mathbb R^2 \times \{0\}$ which has itself as a tangent plane at all points. But $Df$ is $0$ at $(0,0)$.